# Open activity automatically when push notification received

Tags: android

How to open an activity when getting notification. I already did when we click notification it will open activity. But Now I want when I get the push notification from firebase it automatically open my activity.(Without user interaction)

Comment: Ok bro.But often see jio advertisement like this.

Comment: add code........

Answer (score -1):

Called Your Activity via Intent in onMessageReceived Method

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

Intent intent=new Intent(NotificationFirebaseMessagingService.this,TestActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

}